# How to reuse my local dependency while running maven executable jar?

Tags: java, maven, build, maven-assembly-plugin

I have maven project required dependencies in my local, I need to create an executable jar without dependency and need to use those dependencies in my local during the runtime, instead of packing it along with the project.
how to create a maven project jar without dependency in eclipse and how to execute that jar feeding the local location where the dependencies exist?

Comment: might be answered already in [how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mvn dependency:build-classpath` to generate the necessary classpath to run your jar

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/build-classpath-mojo.html

and then run your jar with `java` and adding the generated classpath as `-cp` argument.